# Laravel mix version a specific file

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am trying to version a specific file.

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  .babel([
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js'
  ], 'public/js/libs.js')
  .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'public/js/xxxx.js')
  .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'public/js/xxxx.js')
  .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'public/js/xxxx.js')
  .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'public/js/xxxx.js')
  .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'public/js/xxxx.js')
  .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'public/js/xxxx.js')
  .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'public/js/xxxx.js')
  .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'public/js/xxxx.js')
  .version([
    'public/js/app.js'
  ]);
```

I am trying to version app.js but I get the error:
**Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/js/app.js'**

I have also tried: `app.*.js`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is kind of messy and less readable to chain methods this way with Laravel Mix. If you just want to version the file `app.js`, you could isolate it.

After some tests, I noticed that the `public/` is optional at the beginning of the output path.

Try something like this:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'css/app.css');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js/app.js');

mix.babel([
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js',
    'resources/assets/js/libs/xxxx.js'
], 'js/libs.js');

mix.scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'js/xxxx.js')
    .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'js/xxxx.js')
    .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'js/xxxx.js')
    .scripts('resources/assets/js/pages/xxxx.js', 'js/xxxx.js');

mix.version(['public/js/app.js']);
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

TL;DR: The `version()` method versions all files no matter what.

After taking a look at the [`Versioning` class's source code of the laravel-mix package](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/master/src/Versioning.js) I understood that it is not possible to version only certain files that are present in the `mix-manifest.json` file (i.e. the files you mentioned in your `webpack.mix.js`).

The `version()` method versions all files no matter what. The optional array as argument only indicates if there are more files to version in addition of all the files mentioned in the `mix-manifest.json`.

In your case the `mix.version(['public/js/app.js']);` line firstly versions all the files and secondly looks for the file located at `public/js/app.js`. But it does not exist since it has already been versioned and the files in `public/js` are named `[file-name].[hash].js`. This is why you are getting this error:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/js/app.js'

For example, if your `webpack.mix.js` looks like this:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');

mix.version(['resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js']);
```

Then the files `public/css/app.css`, `public/js/app.js` and `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js` will be versioned.

Comment: Even if I dont chain my methods and only put ``version();`` on app.js just like you it will version ALL files, I have no idea why : /

Comment: I am starting to think that I have to run my webpack mix file twice, and onde of the times I run version

Comment: See my edited answer. That should work. Then you just have to run `npm run dev`, `npm run watch` or `npm run production`. The versioning will happen automatically.

Comment: I tried the edited I still get **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/js/app.js'** I am using Laravel 5.4 wen mix v0.8.9

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why this error is returned. I guess the only solution now is to open a pull request ;)

Comment: @louisfischer - can you also teach me how to run `.version()` with `copyDirectory()`? thank you very much!